# "the X, to Y and which I do Z"

Tags: grammaticality

Let's say I look up to Alice and Bob. Can I convey this fact about Bob in a comma-delimited clause like this?

> This is Bob, up to Alice and whom I look.

or similarly

> My couch, on my bed and which I often sleep, is brown.

Of course I'd avoid this awkward phrasing in practice, but I'm curious whether it's considered technically valid.

Comment: Neither one makes any sense.

Comment: No. These violate the [Coordinate Structure Constraint](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html).

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JohnLawler How come they violate the Coordinate Structure Constraint? Coordination seems OK by me. Is there a constraint that a relative pronoun may not coordinate with a noun or pronoun? If so, fine, but that's not the constraint mentioned in the web page you linked to.

Comment: @RosieF The Coordinate Structure Constraint is a constraint on movement rules, not coordination itself. If a structure is coordinated (A and B), then if you move something out of A or B you must also move it out of B (_the dishes, which Ed washed and bill dried_, which both move _which_ to the front. But you can't say *_the dishes, which Ed washed and Bill dried them_. Read the whole link; the CSC is just one of the Ross constraints.

Comment: @JohnLawler Let's see if I understand: The relevant examples in the web page about Ross constraints are *wh-* questions, in which a trace is where something was moved *from*, and the *wh-* interrogative is its replacement where it was moved *to*. By contrast, here, the *wh-* word is a relative pronoun where a noun was moved *from*, and that noun is its antecedent. If I'm correct, I got confused because I thought the relative pronoun corresponded to an interrogative. But "This is Bob; I work with Alice and him." is OK, so how can a pronoun be the result of movement?

Comment: I didn't mention traces; that's somebody else's invisible stuff. Both question-formation and relative-formation are movement rules that shift _wh_-words to the front from somewhere afterwards. But they can't come from inside certain structures, of which relative clauses are one type, coordinate structures another,  and embedded questions still another type.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely not. They're not grammatical and don't make sense.

The first one could be rephrased, "This is Bob and Alice, up to whom I look." That's grammatical, but it's painfully convoluted and unnatural. It would never happen in conversation or writing.

Use something like: "This is Bob and Alice. I look up to them." Or if you absolutly have to get that *whom* in: "This Bob and Alice, whom I look up to."

The second one simply can't be untangled. Your couch is probably not on your bed, right? So which do you sleep on? The couch or the bed? Which one is brown?

Try again!

Comment: Well, they are not grammatical but they do make sense. The intended meaning is clear.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Not to me. I applaud Charlie for untangling the meaning of the first one.

Comment: @Barmar The second one means that the couch is brown and that the speaker often sleeps on his bed and on the couch.

Comment: I don't see how 'That's grammatical, but it's painfully convoluted and unnatural. It would never happen in conversation or writing.' really works. There comes a time when the grammar has to change to align with actual usage.